# Jquery easeOutBounce direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to use a Jquery menu, that makes use of the 'easeOutBounce' easing method. It is working fine but, I cannot figure out how to change the direction that the menu is bouncing out from. It currently expands to the right and bounces. My menu will be right-align and I want it to expand to the left.

This is the example I'm using: http://jcargoo.110mb.com/rightmenu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://demo.raleighbuckner.com/so/1338381/

If so, all I did (other than removing the extra examples) is to change this CSS:

```
#sliding-navigation1 li {
    text-align: right;
    }
```

to this:

```
#sliding-navigation1 li {
    text-align: right;
    float:right;
    clear:both;
    }
```